# Is there any way to retain word 2010 format?

Tags: libreoffice, pdf, format, cpu

I have some resumes and other documents that are really format dependent. They were originally created with Microsoft Word 2010, and is there any way to put them into ubuntu and have them still be editable (not in pdf form.) When I tried opening them in libreoffice they opened fine, but the format was all messed up.

Comment: Try Abiword. My experience is that Libreffice centred test but Abiword was correct.

Answer (score 1):

Not ideal but worth mentioning: you can use Microsoft Office webapps in any browser: http://office.microsoft.com . It's free to register, and you get some storage space for documents.

Note that LibreOffice is getting better and better at handling MS document formats, so try to get the latest version of LO, it should work well for most documents, and for the really critical documents use MS Office webapp.

Answer (score 0):

My experience with this is that some formats are better than others, but the more exotic features you use LibreOffice gets it more wrong.

You can try to save to a different file format from MS Word (Word95, RTF, ...). MS Word even has a open document plugin you can try.